# OfficeJs Header Content Controls

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to obtain the content controls of the header but I can't get them.
I ended up using ooxml but it was a bit painful.

```
function getContenControlHeader(tag) {

    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
        var mySections = context.document.sections;

        // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
        context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader('primary');
            return context.sync().then(function () {

                var contentControl = myHeader.contentControls.getByTag(tag);

                // Queue a command to load the text property for a content control.
                context.load(contentControl, 'text');

                // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                        console.log(contentControl.items[0].text);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This snippet does not work, the returned list is empty. This same snippet for content controls on the document body works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in the most recent publicly available build (16.7766)in Word and its working, as long as I provide a valid Tag. Probably goes without saying but:
a. please check that a content control with the tag you are providing to the getByTag actually  exists in the header.

it this is still not working please provide more information:
a. are you testing this in Windows, Online, Mac?
b. build number.

I also recommend you to catch an exception to find out more details about what might be going on check the handler I added to your sample:

```js
function getContenControlHeader(tag) {

    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
        var mySections = context.document.sections;

        // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
        context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader('primary');
            return context.sync().then(function () {

                var contentControl = myHeader.contentControls.getByTag("sample");

                // Queue a command to load the text property for a content control.
                context.load(contentControl, 'text');

                // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    console.log(contentControl.items[0].text);
                });
            });
        });
    })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
        }   ) 
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer. Tried this and didn't work, I'll try it now. Thanks.

Comment: hello, its not clear to me if you actually tried my sample. did you> and if not what error you are getting and also provide more details on your office client build etc. thanks